# With an xml jinja2 template, how to explode an element based on text field into multiple elements?

Tags: python, xml, jinja2, lxml

I have a jinja2 xml template

```
<final_tag>{{some_tag}}</final_tag>
```

I have a context with a string containing ",".

```
 {"some_tag" : "a,b,c"}
```

How can I use jinja2 to explode the string into multiple elements?

```
 <final_tag>"a"</final_tag>
 <final_tag>"b"</final_tag>
 <final_tag>"c"</final_tag>
```

Is there some smart feature or do I have to start thinking about not using jinja2 for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the string and iterate over the result:

```
{% for value in some_tag.split(',') %}
<final_tag>"{{ value }}"</final_tag>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to write this as like a filter to pass to Jinja 2 environment? I am trying to automate this such that if we stumble upon such a string it would automatically understand that it should explode. So not having to hardcode it into the template.

Comment: Sure, Jinja has support for custom filters. Just write the corresponding Python function and then register it by on the `filters` attribute of a Jinja environment. See "[Custom Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#writing-filters)" documentation for more information.